# If the order of $H$ equals the order of $x$ in $H$ then $x$ generates $H.$

Tags: group-theory

> If the order of $H$ equals the order of $x$ in $H$ then $x$ generates $H.$

My attempt was:
assume $y \in H$ such that $y \neq x^{k}$ $\forall 1 \leq k \leq n$
we know that order of y should be some integer $\leq n $ say t then
$y^{t} = x^{n}$
and also we know that $xy \in H$ then order of xy $\leq n $ say m then
$(xy)^m = e$
$\implies y^{m} = x^{-m}$ now using this how can I arrive at a contradiction?
Is there some other way of proving the same?

Comment: *Hint*: If the order of $x$ is $n$, then $\langle x \rangle = \{1,x,\dots,x^{n-1}\}$ has $n$ elements.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. This question has a clear attempt.

Comment: @Shaun, perhaps some suspect that this could be a homework or exercise problem, which could be problematic.

Answer (score 2):

This fails when $H$ is infinite. For example, $2\in\Bbb Z$ has infinite order, so does $\Bbb Z$, but $2$ does not generate $\Bbb Z$.

---

Let $|H|=n$ be finite. If $x\in H$ has order $n$, then $|\langle x\rangle|=n$, exhausting the elements of $H$, since, indeed, $$\langle x\rangle\le H,$$

meaning $n=\lvert\langle x\rangle \rvert\le |H|=n$ by, say, Lagrange's Theorem. Thus $\langle x\rangle =H.$ In other words, $x$ generates $H$.